# Django redirect_url with parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a simple `UpdateView` which updates instances of my `Profile` model.

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

It's working fine both `GET` and `POST`, but since the `GET` uses an url parameter, I want also the `redirect_url` to redirect to the updated profile.

My current urls.py:

```
from profiles.views import ProfileUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('self/<slug:slug>', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(success_url='/'), name='self_profile')
]
```

It is currently redirecting to the main url, but I don't figure out how to make the `redirect_url` parameter redirect to the profile modified on the handled `POST`.

Let's say I do `http://localhost:8000/profiles/self/demo`, (GET), then I modify my `first_name` and submit the request. I want the redirection to go to `/profiles/self/demo` again.

I know I could override `def post()` on the view and achieve it, but since I only want to deal with the redirection I wanted to know if exists any other elegant solution.

***EDIT***:
Additional info: the slug url parameter will always be request.user in this case (since I use other view (a `DetailView`) to see other users' profiles).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`get_success_url(...)`** method as

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/profiles/self/demo'
```

Hence, you don't need to specify the **`success_url`** attribute in the urls.py

```
from profiles.views import ProfileUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('self/<slug:slug>', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='self_profile')
]
```